# How to fix "The Component for route 'Principal' must be a React Component" error in React-Native

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react-native and I've encountered this problem:
**(The component for route 'Principal' must be a React component.For example:...)**.

I want to put a DrawerNavigator inside a StackNavigator.
I have seen that it is good way but it gives me this error I have been looking but I am unable to solve it.

Thanks

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {createAppContainer,createStackNavigator,createDrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import Login from './pantallas/login';
import Registro from './pantallas/registro';
import PantallaPrincipal from './pantallas/pantallaPrincipal';
import SolicitudCitas from './pantallas/socitudCitas';
import {Header,Icon} from 'native-base';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer/>;
  }
}

const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Login: { screen: Login },
  Registro: { screen: Registro },
  Principal: {screen: AppDrawerNavigator}
},{
  headerMode: 'none',
  navigationOptions: {
    headerVisible: false,
  }
}
);

const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    PantallaPrincipal:{screen: PantallaPrincipal},
    SolicitudCitas: {screen: SolicitudCitas}}
    ,{
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
          headerLeft: (
            <Header>
              <Icon
                style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}
                onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
                name="menu"
                size={30}/>
            </Header>
          )
        };
      }
    }
  );

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppStackNavigator);
```

pantallaPrincipal.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View,StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class pantallaPrincipal extends Component {
    
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.backgroundContainer}>
        <Text>Pantalla principal</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundContainer : {
    flex: 1,
    width: null,
    height: null,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
});
```

solicitudCitas.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class solicitudCitas extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <Text>Solicitud Citas</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply declare & initialize your DrawerNavigator above your Stack navigator in which you are using it. It is just happening due to hoisting fundamental of JS. In javascript, only declarations are hoisted, not initialization, so when you are using the `Principal: {screen: AppDrawerNavigator}`, JS doesn't know that `AppDrawerNavigator` is actually a React component since it is not being initialized prior to its usage. You can study more about hoisting in JS [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting).